# Load a Excel file with images using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm currently working on a project that needs to display excel files (xls, xlsx, csv) on the browser. So far, I have tried and used the PHPExcel library and was able to display the excel file (code below)

```
$opendoc     = $userDoc;
$objReader   = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($opendoc);
$objWriter   = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objw        = $objWriter;
$objw->writeAllSheets(); 
$objw->save('php://output');
```

The problem I'm encountering is that this code does not support the displaying images (charts , graph , etc) inside an excel file. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errr..... yes it does. Have you read the documentation or looked at the examples? Images are supported directly, and (unless you tell PHPExcel to load data only) should always be loaded.

For charts and graphs, you specifically have to tell PHPExcel to load them when reading a file, and tell PHPExcel to save them when Writing. ([Example](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/36chartreadwriteHTML.php))

```
$opendoc     = $userDoc;
$objReader   = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();

$objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($opendoc);
$objWriter   = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objw        = $objWriter;

$objw->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);

$objw->writeAllSheets(); 
$objw->save('php://output');
```

Comment: hi mark! thanks for this. but the image being reflected to my browser is broken any ideas?

Comment: No I have no ideas, because I haven't a clue what your spreadsheet is like, so I can't know what it should look like, or what it does look like